# Has anyone ever used the Spiderflex seat on a roadbike?

Tags: road-bike, saddle

I use a spiderflex seat on my mountain bike, and I would like to use this on a road bike.  Has anyone ever done this, or something similar?

I am 5'10" and 165 lbs (reasonably fit).

Yes, I know the 'the saddle horn is used for steering.....'  - but the spiderflex on my MTB annihilates chafing and discomfort. And I do about 20 miles a day on the spiderflex with ZERO - absolute ZERO pain or chafing.

I know I will forfeit cornering and maneuverability without a horn.  Has anyone ever used such a seat successfully on a ROAD BIKE?
Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you will break one of "The Rules" (http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/), but do what works for you

Comment: They have testimonials from road bikers on their web site.

Comment: I am voting to close this as both primarily opinion based and verging on a product recommendation/review.

Answer (score 4):

From this question and the other regarding clothes, I think that you would be better off showing the bike or bikes you are referring to when using the term "road bike".

Possibly you are not talking of a road bike like this:
[image: hard road]

Because it would be just a waste of the money invested in weight reduction / aerodynamics to use it in plain clothes and with a beastly saddle.

Now if you refer to something like this:
[image: relaxed road]

I would say a saddle like the one pictured is comfy enough for 11 miles, but you can uglify the bike for comfiness sake, police will not fine you. And casual clothes would fit perfectly aestethically.

Answer (score 1):

What’s your seating position? I guess you are sitting pretty upright.

I doubt this seat will work with the stretched and deep position on a road bike. Especially when using the drops.